# VB.NET Declaring new SQL Connection

Tags: vb.net, string, connection

I have a public class within a module and there is a variable which holds my connection string like this:

```
Public ConnectionS As New SqlConnection("Data Source(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
```

The code above works and saves my Connection string correctly. However when I save my connection string to My.Settings.ConnectionS and use the following code:

```
Public ConnectionS As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionS)
```

It doesn't save the connection string. When I use the first code above and output the value of ConnectionS into a textbox I get the exact connection string above but when I output the value of the second code I get nothing (blank textbox). I don't understand why because I have my connection string saved to My.Settings.ConnectionS in my application settings.

Comment: How are you saving the connection string to My.Settings?

Comment: Have you tried to output this and make sure ***it's actually stored in your settings?***

Comment: I manually put it into My.Settings.ConnectionS and it is outputting when I do textbox.text = My.settings.connections . Also in the settings the ConnectionS variable is declared a User scope and String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you aren't saving the connection the correct way.  Instead of saving the setting, you are instantiating a new setting but never actually saving that value to the user setting.  The correct way to save your connection to My.Settings would be as follows:

```
My.Settings.ConnectionS = New SqlConnection("Data Source(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
My.Settings.Save()
```

Also, be sure that you've set up the ConnectionS setting with a type of SqlConnection.
Here is more information on saving user settings if you need it:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwc80dzb.aspx

Comment: Can't I just save the connection string to a string in my.settings ? Also I'm trying out the code you gave me , I hope it solves everything :D

Comment: Yes, you can also just save it as a string and build the connection with the saved string when you need it.  May be easier that way.

Comment: Thanks I did it your way and it worked perfectly. I didn't realize that you need to actually declare it as "New SqlConnection" I thought you can just paste the string. But it works now so that's good, thank you.